# What will be the sum of the numbers in the $100^{\text{th}}$ step?

Tags: combinatorics

So this question states that a triangle is found where in between every $2$ numbers, their sum will be found in the next step, an example can be found below for the first $3$ steps. The question asks what will be the sum of the numbers in the $100^{\text{th}}$ step? I managed to find a pattern that states $S_n=S_{n-1}+2 \times 3^{n-1}$ if $S_k$ is the sum of step $k$. However, is this pattern correct and if it is then why? Also, can this triangle relate to Pascal's triangle? Thank you anyways.

[image]

Comment: But the third row adds to $28$, your formula gives $26$. Can you write one more row?

Comment: @Krishna I noticed that this triangle is similar to Pascal's and that is how I got the $2^n$ in my equation. However, the second part of my equation would be the harder one to prove as it does not have a huge relation with Pascal's triangle.

Comment: @farruhota Thank you for that notice I realized I had a mistake and meant to say $S_n=S_{n-1}+2 \times 3^{n-1}$ This will be fixed.

Comment: I do not understand how the third row is made from the second, let alone how subsequent rows are made.

Comment: @Servaes The same numbers from the second row have been written down again but this time with an extra number between each $2$ numbers being their sum. So the $4$ came from being the sum of $1+3$ and the from the $5$ sum of $3+2$

Comment: $S_n=3S_{n-1}-2, n>1; S_1=4$

Comment: This is triangular [OEIS sequence A049456](https://oeis.org/A049456) which states row sums are [OEIS sequence A034472](https://oeis.org/A034472)  3^n+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every number in the $n+1$-th row either comes directly from the $n$-th row, or is the sum of two neighbouring numbers in the $n$-th row. Every number in the $n$-th row has two neighbours (except the first and last) and so it is in two sums. So in summing the $n+1$-th row, we in fact sum every number from the $n$-th row *three times* (except the first and last). This yields the recursive formula
$$S_{n+1}=3S_n-2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence equation is also correct. Note that:
$$S_n=S_{n-1}+2\cdot 3^{n-1}, S_1=4 \Rightarrow \frac{S_n}{3^n}=\frac13\cdot \frac{S_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}+\frac23 \Rightarrow \\
a_n=\frac13a_{n-1}+\frac23, a_1=\frac43 \Rightarrow a_n=\left(\frac13\right)^n+1=\frac{S_n}{3^n} \Rightarrow \\
S_n=3^n+1.$$